# How to convert String to Array in Scala.html?

Tags: scala

I don't know convert String to array in Play scala. String contains
`"test1,test2,test3,test4"`. I want to split a string into array like

```
a[0]=test1,a[1]=test2,a[3]=test3,a[4]=test4
```

Comment: So you're looking for a function: `String => Array[String]`? Example: `f("test1,test2,test3,test4") == Array("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")`?

Comment: yes, have any solution to convert? and how to do in scala.html

Comment: I tried this one but getting some errors Array[java.lang.String] items = (@Testing.values).split(",")

Comment: Although I directly answered your question, what are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> "test1,test2,test3,test4".split(",")
res1: Array[String] = Array(test1, test2, test3, test4)
```